# Do web applications keep getting completely rebuilt between requests?

Tags: asp.net, http, web-applications

Given that HTTP is a stateless protocol, does IIS keep 'rebuilding' a requested web application for every user and every request?

Suppose a user arrives to a login page.  IIS builds the web application and returns the login page to the client.  The client enters his credentials and is then taken to the landing page of his account.  Was the entire web application rebuilt just to get him from the login screen to the landing page?

I have been reviewing the literature on the asp.net web app life cycle but can't seem to find a clear answer on this.

Comment: Generally speaking using a standard configuration the application would be compiled for the first request only.

Comment: @Calvedos: or before the first request, most likely

Comment: Yep, I'd agree with that.

Answer (score 1):

ASP.Net applications are usually already compiled before they are deployed to your IIS server.

What happens is that IIS will load your application when the first http request is received. For other requests, they will only be served by IIS as the app is already loaded.

The fact that http is stateless does not have any correlation with how the app is manager by IIS. It only means that no state is maintained at the protocol level between 2 requests.